# Laravel 5.1 Query Building

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have three tables.

Table 1

- id
- name

Table 2

- id
- price
- table1_id (reference to id of table 1)

Table 3

- id
- image
- table1_id (reference to id of table 1)

How can I build a query to display the result as JSON in the following format?

```json
{

    'data':[
        id:1
        name:'test'
        price:13
        images:[
            'link1',
            'link2'
        ]

     ]

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = DB::table('Table 1 as t1')
                  ->leftjoin('Table 2 AS t2', 't2.table1_id', '=', 't1.id')
                  ->leftjoin('Table 3 AS t3', 't3.table1_id', '=', 't1.id')
                  ->select(array('t1.*','t2.*','t3.*'))
                  ->get();
return response()->json($data);
```